# C++ file cannot find library linked with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, imgui

I wanted to use DearImGui therefore I needed to either copy ImGui into the project or use a package manager, so I chose the latter. I'm currently using Conan as a my package manager, the file looks like this: 
*conanfile.txt*

```
[requires]
boost/1.79.0
imgui/1.88
glad/0.1.36
glfw/3.3.7

[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

It has all the dependancies as a normal ImGui project would need as well as boost which had been downloaded as a binary previously and works fine, using just a normal header like `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`. I figure this happens because it was aleady installed.

I have a basic file structure that looks like this, prebuild:

```
conanfile.txt
CMakeLists.txt
src -
    main.cpp
```

With this main CMakeLists I set up a linker with conan and simple setup instructions like the project name, executable, and the libraries

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(RenderCam CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/conan_paths.cmake)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

find_package(Boost 1.79.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system filesystem)

if(TARGET boost::boost)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} boost::boost)
endif()

find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)

if(TARGET glfw)
    message("Found GLFW")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)
endif()

find_package(imgui 1.88 REQUIRED)

if(TARGET imgui::imgui)
    message("found imgui")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} imgui::imgui)
endif()
```

After running two commands (`conan install ..` and `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`) in the new build directory the CMake build responds with all the found messages for the project as well as the location of the files, which should be expected. Though when add the `#include <imgui.h>` to the main.cpp it states the file is not found which shouldn't be if I have linked it. On the other hand `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` has no errors and I can go upon my day with all of the commands. I would just like to include the directories and have tried multiple steps and guides before I took it here. For further reference, this is my conanprofile :

```
Configuration for profile default:

[settings]
os=Macos
os_build=Macos
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=apple-clang
compiler.version=13
compiler.libcxx=libc++
build_type=Release
[options]
[conf]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

Comment: `if(TARGET boost::boost)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} boost::boost)
endif()`??? Why do you check for the target here? If `find_package` is unsuccessful, the cmake configuration step fails anyways, since you added the `REQUIRED` option. Should be just `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Boost::threads Boost::system Boost::filesystem)`

Comment: That's a fair point as it makes it cleaner and there really was no need for it to be split into separate ```target_link_libraries```. Though that wasn't the problem as imgui still isn't included, even after adding ```imgui::imgui``` underneath Boost::boost. This should be the correct path because when building the CMakeLists I get this message: ```Conan: Component target declared 'Boost::boost'``` which is the same case for imgui. This error still occurs even when switching from PRIVATE to PUBLIC

Comment: Don't use `cmake_find_package` & `CMakeDeps` together, these 2 generators are mutually exclusive and may conflict. Since you have `CMakeToolchain` generator, `cmake_paths` is useless. And make sure to set `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path/to/conan_toolchain.cmake>` during cmake configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix up mutually exclusive generators like `cmake_find_package` vs `CMakeDeps`, or `cmake_paths` vs `CMakeToolchain`.

Here is a basic example of non-intrusive integration of conan:

conanfile.txt

```ini
[requires]
boost/1.79.0
imgui/1.88
glfw/3.3.7

[generators]
CMakeToolchain
CMakeDeps
```

CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(RenderCam CXX)

find_package(Boost 1.79.0 REQUIRED thread system filesystem)
find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(imgui 1.88 REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Boost::headers Boost::thread Boost::system Boost::filesystem glfw imgui::imgui)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_14)
```

Install dependencies, configure & build:

```sh
mkdir build && cd build
conan install .. -s build_type=Release -b missing
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build . --config Release
```